# Get only last record of JOIN in MySQL

Tags: mysql, left-join, outer-join

I have 2 tables A, B where B contains a foreign key to A

```
ida,cola1
idb,fka,colb1
```

For each record from A I need to get only the last result of LEFT OUTER JOIN. The following query displays all JOINs, how to limit it to the last occurence of fka only?

```
SELECT ida,idb,cola1,colb1 FROM a LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON ida=fka
```

Comment: How do you define _last result_? This will likely involve a group by on table A column(s) with an aggregate function on B column that defines _last result_, then join back to B to get additional row data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the last result in table b is the one with the highest idb, then one solution is to use a subquery where you calculate max(idb) for each fka:

```
select
  a.ida,
  a.cola1,
  b.idb,
  b.fka,
  b.colb1
from
  a left outer join (
    select fka, max(idb) as max_idb
    from b
    group by fka
  ) max_b on a.ida=max_b.fka
  left outer join b on max_b.fka=b.fka and max_b.max_idb=b.idb
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    ida,idb,cola1,colb1 
FROM a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON ida=fka 
ORDER BY ida DESC LIMIT 1
```

May Be this one is Help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group by` to remove all other columns from the table `B`
then join the to the table `A` to get the result
`Group by` requires an `aggregate function` like `min` or `max` etc

Here I tried it with `min`

```
SELECT 
    ida, idb, cola1, colb1 
FROM A LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    select 
        min(idb) idb, fka, min(colb1) colb1
    from B
    group by fka
) b
ON ida = fka
```